# How can I remove the header and footer rules from a letter with the newlfm class?

Tags: header-footer, letters, newlfm

```
\documentclass[12pt]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}
\sbox{\Luiuc}{%
    \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%
        \vspace{0.5in}%
        \includegraphics[scale=1.0]
    }%
}%
\makeletterhead{GRIET}{\Lheader{\usebox{\LGRIET}}}

\newlfmP{}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{Letter of recommendations} 
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=20pt}
\lthUiuc


\namefrom{(Prof. Dr. Mohammed Hussain)}
\addrfrom{% 
}

\addrto{%
Dr. Mohammed Hussain\\
Professor and Head of the Department,\\
School of Civil Engineering,\\
GRIET,\\
Bachupally,\\
Phone:+91-996-388-0472,\\
Email: hod-civil@griet.ac.in.}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of \ldots{}

he has done a good job

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Could you edit your question's title to be a bit more meaningful? It isn't at all clear when it is read in the list of question what `those lines` and `that document` refer to!

Comment: @Down-voters: why?? Please do not vote a post down without leaving a comment explaining how it can be improved. Especially when a user has only just joined the site and has posted their first question. While the formatting of this question needed some improvement and while some explanation in the question and a better title would be good, it is far better than many first questions and includes all the basics such as code.

Comment: I've gone ahead and changed the title of your question. Please check that it reflects what you want to ask. You can edit your question to change it if not. I just wanted to dissuade further down voting, if possible.

Comment: I can't compile your code, though. Can you fix it, please?

Answer (score 1):

Note that I had to modify your code in order to even compile it and that I've, therefore, had to guess as to what you might have meant in several places.

`noLines` removes the lines on the first page. `nolines` removes it on subsequent pages.

[image: lineless letter]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter,graphicx}
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newsavebox{\Luiuc}
\sbox{\Luiuc}{%
  \parbox[b]{1.75in}{%
    \vspace{0.5in}%
    \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image-a}%
  }%
}%
\makeletterhead{GRIET}{\Lheader{\usebox{\LGRIET}}}

\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt,dateskipafter=20pt,stdletter,noLines,nolines}

\namefrom{(Prof. Dr. Mohammed Hussain)}
\addrfrom{%
}

\addrto{%
Dr. Mohammed Hussain\\
Professor and Head of the Department,\\
School of Civil Engineering,\\
GRIET,\\
Bachupally,\\
Phone:+91-996-388-0472,\\
Email: hod-civil@griet.ac.in.}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of \ldots{}

he has done a good job

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```